# Can I use LinqToExcel for saving edited data to excel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-excel

I am using LinqToExcel for sorting of data. I want to save sorted data back to excel. For that is there any function in LinqToExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) project page, it is designed for querying data, not modifying data. So no, there is not anything built into LinqToExcel to allow this.

To modify an Excel sheet, you will need to use either the Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO), Open Office XML, or a third-party library that wraps one of these.

Comment: Okay Thanks.. I am using EPPlus to do excel operations. I will check by using both LinqToExcel for sorting data and for updating excel and let you know.